# What set do these large white pieces with Technic pins and an orange winch come from?

Tags: set-identification

I found this at home with many other scattered parts and set, but I'm unsure what this one belongs to. What set is it from?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like part of a Jack Stone [4618-1: Twin Rotor Cargo](https://brickset.com/sets/4618-1/Twin-Rotor-Cargo)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alexander O'Mara answered it quite well but if you are looking for instructions as well, then [toysperiod](https://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/4-juniors/jack-stone/airport/lego-4618-twin-rotor-cargo/) have you covered.

[image]